# Model Binding with optional parameter in angular and web api 2

Tags: c#, angularjs, web

i have a Model in web api

```
  public class myModel{
public string FirstName{get;set;}
public string LastName{get;set;}
public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Web api Controller

```
public string saveRecord(myModel data){

return data;
}
```

angular post ....

```
  function(){
    var obj={
    FirstName:'Robin',
    Age:24
    }

$http.post(myurl,{ obj}).then(function(rp){
alert(rp.data);
}


}
```

i have passed only two parameter in post.
now i am getting all values is null in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a new object and config the headers:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";  

var myModel = new obj();
myModel.FirstName = "Robin";
myModel.Age = 24;

$http.post(myurl, JSON.stringify(myModel));
```